# play framework content type application/xml

Tags: xml, playframework, mime-types, content-type

I'm implementing a REST webservice using Play! version 2.0.4.

After a couple of tests - using curl to request a resource - I notice that Play! only accepts XML with the following Content-Type: text/xml. According with W3 both text/xml and application/xml are valid MIME types.

From: http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/

> The media types 'application/xml' and 'text/xml' may also be used, but
>   whenever appropriate, 'application/xhtml+xml' or 'text/html' should be
>   used rather than those generic XML media types.

The problem. In my code I have something like:

```
106: if (request().getHeader("Content-Type").contains("text/xml")
107:            || request().getHeader("Content-Type").contains("application/xml")) {
108:        
109:        Document xml = request().body().asXml();
110:        Node root = XPath.selectNode("cost", xml);
        ...
}
```

If the Content-Type equals text/xml everything works fine but for the other site if the Content-Type is equal to application/xml the Play! framework returns `null` in the assignment `Document xml = request().body().asXml();`

Below are the list commands - using curl - that I've used to test the web service:

```
$ curl -i -X POST -d @input.xml -H "Content-Type: text/xml" \
http://localhost:9000/costs

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Length: 146

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><cost>3089219.0</cost>

$ curl -i -X POST -d @input.xml -H "Content-Type: application/xml" \
http://localhost:9000/costs

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 5231

...
[RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException]
In (...)/app/controllers/Application.java at line 110.
...
```

Is this a bug or it's the normal behavior?

Thanks!

*Ricardo F. Teixeira*

Answer (score 1):

Now I'm not necessarily able to answer to whether or not this is intended, but I also had run into the same problem and managed a workaround for this situation.

You should be able to receive your `request().body().asRaw().asBytes()`, which will return a `byte[]`.

From there, it can be used to construct a `ByteArrayInputStream` which `Document` will accept as an argument for it's own construction.

```
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory().newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document xml = docBuilder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(request().body().asRaw().asBytes()));
```

Comment: Well I think I'm going to use your approach : ) Better than nothing.

Thanks!